# NSMutableArray losing added data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

For learning purposes, I am creating a simple app that will calculate the weeks between two dates. 
For this I have created

- BITInputViewController : UITableViewController   (contains 2 rows, with each one date)
- BITSelectDateViewController : UIViewController (contains a UIDatePicker to select the date)

I BITInputViewController I have created a NSMutableArray datesArray with objects "start date" and "end date".

```
-(id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Calculate weeks";

    datesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Start date", @"End date", nil];
}
return self;
```

}

If I go to the BITSelectDateViewcontroller, the selected date should be added to this Array. 
NSLogs in BITSelectDateViewController show that the date is added to the datesArray. However if I go back to BITInputViewController, this entry is lost and only the start and end date is in the Array.

So what am I missing?

BITInputViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BITSelectDateViewController.h"

@interface BITInputViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *datesArray;

-(void)passDate:(NSString *)dateString;

@end
```

BITInputViewController.m

```
-(void)passDate:(NSString *)dateString {

   [datesArray addObject:dateString];

    NSLog(@"<IVC> passdate:(NSString *)dateString %@",dateString);

    NSLog(@"<IVC> rowcount datesArray %d", [datesArray count]);

    for (NSObject *d in datesArray) {
        NSLog(@"<IVC> Dump of passdate:(NSString *)dateString %@",d);
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for (NSString *d in datesArray) {
        NSLog(@"<IVC> viewWillAppear: datesArray: %@",d);
    }

    NSLog(@" %p", datesArray);

}
```

BITSelectedDateViewController.m

```
- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"<SDV> LabelChange: method");

    BITInputViewController *vc = [[BITInputViewController alloc]init];


    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

    [vc passDate:dateLabel.text];

    NSLog(@"<SDV> LabelChange: to passDate %@:",dateLabel.text);

     if (vc.datesArray) {

    for (NSString *d in vc.datesArray) {
        NSLog(@"<SDV> Dump of datesrray in labelChange: %@",d);
    }
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"<SDV>!ivc.datesArray");

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[self view] endEditing:YES];

    NSLog(@"<SDV>dateLabel in viewWillDisappear: %@", dateLabel.text);

}
```

If you look at the LOG you will see the date is added to the Array, but back in InputViewController it is lost.

```
2013-03-04 14:06:11.713[28900:c07] <IVC> viewWillAppear: datesArray: Start date
2013-03-04 14:06:11.714[28900:c07] <IVC> viewWillAppear: datesArray: End date
2013-03-04 14:06:11.717[28900:c07] set dates
2013-03-04 14:06:11.719[28900:c07] set dates
2013-03-04 14:06:13.533[28900:c07] <SDV> datelabel viewWillAppear Mar 4, 2013
2013-03-04 14:06:14.895[28900:c07] <SDV> LabelChange: method
2013-03-04 14:06:14.897[28900:c07] <IVC> passdate:(NSString *)dateString Mar 5, 2013
2013-03-04 14:06:14.897[28900:c07] <IVC> aantal rijen in datesArray 3
2013-03-04 14:06:14.898[28900:c07] <IVC> Dump of passdate:(NSString *)dateString Start date
2013-03-04 14:06:14.898[28900:c07] <IVC> Dump of passdate:(NSString *)dateString End date
2013-03-04 14:06:14.899[28900:c07] <IVC> Dump of passdate:(NSString *)dateString Mar 5, 2013
2013-03-04 14:06:14.899[28900:c07] <SDV> LabelChange: to passDate Mar 5, 2013:
2013-03-04 14:06:14.900[28900:c07] <SDV> Dump of datesrray in labelChange: Start date
2013-03-04 14:06:14.900[28900:c07] <SDV> Dump of datesrray in labelChange: End date
2013-03-04 14:06:14.901[28900:c07] <SDV> Dump of datesrray in labelChange: Mar 5, 2013
2013-03-04 14:06:16.489[28900:c07] <SDV>dateLabel in viewWillDisappear: Mar 5, 2013
2013-03-04 14:06:16.489[28900:c07] <IVC> viewWillAppear: datesArray: Start date
2013-03-04 14:06:16.490[28900:c07] <IVC> viewWillAppear: datesArray: End date
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. NSMutableArray was losing it's data, because I didn't set the property in 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

```
 BITSelectDateViewController  *selectDateViewController = [[BITSelectDateViewController alloc] init];    
 selectDateViewController.vc = self;// Set this property as you prepare the selectDateViewController

 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectDateViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *datesArray;
```

Here you make a copy of your array. Your second controller operates on its own copy. You need to pass your array as `strong`/`retain`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick respons, I have changed it to @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *datesArray;
 but it still loses the added date

Comment: and @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *datesArray; doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: Do you use `retain` in both controllers? You can `NSLog(@"%p", array)` to check if you are using single object in both controllers.

Comment: No, I have only one @property declared, in BITInputViewController as shown above.  I have checked using NSLog(@"%p", array), the array gets another address when going back to InputViewController.